# Can't see POST action in Firebug or Chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I can't see that a POST ajax request is being made in Firebug or in Chrome development tool.
I can't see the output of `console.log(data)` inside the success in Firebug, but in Chrome, I can see the output of `console.log(data)`.

Here is my controller, take a look at my comments:

```
var gameApp = angular.module("gameApp", ['ngRoute','ngSanitize']);
gameApp.service('link', function() {
    this.user = false;
});
gameApp.directive('mapActivity', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('tabledata', function() {
             angular.element('.click#1').addClass('dotted').html($("<img src='images/dot.png'>"));          
                var j = null;
                for(var i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'lib/terrain.php',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        data: {i: i},
                        success: function(data) {
                            var randomRuta = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
                            angular.element('.click#'+randomRuta).addClass('monster').html($("<img src='images/blackdot.png' title='"+data+"'>"));                  
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(thrownError); }
                    });
                    j=i;
                }  
                angular.element('.click').click(function() {
                    if(angular.element(this).hasClass('monster'))
                    {
                        if(confirm('Vill du anfalla monster?'))
                        {
                            alert("Du vann");
                            angular.element('.click.monster'+j).empty();
                            angular.element('.click.monster').removeClass('monster'+j);
                            angular.element('.click.dotted').empty();
                            angular.element('.click.dotted').removeClass('dotted');
                            angular.element(this).addClass('dotted');
                            angular.element('.click.dotted').html($('<img src="images/dot.png">'));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        angular.element('.click.dotted').empty();
                        angular.element('.click.dotted').removeClass('dotted');
                        if(!angular.element(this).hasClass('dotted'))
                        {
                            angular.element(this).addClass('dotted');
                            angular.element(this).html($('<img src="images/dot.png">'));
                        }
                    }
                });
            });                     
        }
    };
});

function makeTableFrom(str) {
    var k = 1;
    result = "";
    for(var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        result += '<tr>';
        for(var j = 1; j <= 20; j++) {
            if(str[k] == '#') {
                result += '<td id=' + k + '">#</td>';
            }
            else if(str[k] == '&') {
                result += '<td class="click" val="water" id="' + k + '">&</td>';
            }
            else {
                result += '<td class="click" id="' + k + '"></td>';
            }
            k++;
        }
        result += '</tr>';
    }
    return result;
}          
gameApp.controller("gameCtrl", function($scope,$http,link,$location,$sce,$rootScope) {

    $scope.getMonsters = "1";
    var tabledata = ""; //Variable to store pattern for html table

    $http.post("lib/action.php", {monsters: $scope.getMonsters}).success(function(data) {   //the post action is not outputed either in firebug or chrome

        tabledata = data;   //Assign the pattern
        console.log(tabledata); //This is not printed out in firebug, but I can see the output i chrome

    }).error(function(data) { console.log("error"); });
    $scope.result = makeTableFrom(tabledata); //Call the function to build the table based on the pattern

    console.log("test"); //This is not shown in firebug, but is printed out in chrome. However, the test is printed out TWICE, instead of just one. Why?

    $scope.safeHtml = function() {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.result);
    };
    if(link.user) {
        /*$scope.message = "fisk";
        console.log(link.user);*/
    } else {
        /*$scope.message = "Ledsen fisk";
        console.log("Är inte satt");*/
    }
});
```

Here is my HTML

```
<div ng-controller="gameCtrl">
    <table ng-bind-html="safeHtml()" map-Activity>
    </table>
</div>
```

Anyone have an idea why `console.log` is not working in Firebug and why I can't see that an ajax post request is being made?

Comment: Probably you need to `enable the console` in Firebug. Check if the firebug is working in a static test HTML page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should help you:

http://getfirebug.com/enable

Comment: It was enabled. I just restarted firefox and It worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can even check GET response with Inspect Element option too in Firefox. It is already given. click right in any blank space of your page and then click on network. Now execute anything then see logs there :)